# Rails 4.2 Upgrade to 5 results in ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf-protection

So I have a fully working 4.2 Rails application where I use devise for email login, and a totally devise unrelated omniauth flow for Oauth.

I decided to update to Rails 5.1.2 and got the dreaded CSRF InvalidAuthenticityToken. This happens when trying to login through devise (email) or when using omniauth.

```
Environment: Development


application_controller.rb

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true

...

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_path(id: resource.id)
  end
```

Sessions Controller has nothing relevant, no before_ filters, no particular methods.

```
 Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-09 22:32:25 -0100
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eTJnjnTDNbahT+W8ajr9fH8tGSC0wfismuNbwr0qtQkYoCoFqDm5kZ+nlwAnz+RbLL4v41oqgmqJzaIVJYWxXw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"*****@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"log in"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):

actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:195:in `handle_unverified_request'
```

The html is being rendered with the CSRF headers:

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="eTJnjnTDNbahT+W8ajr9fH8tGSC0wfismuNbwr0qtQkYoCoFqDm5kZ+nlwAnz+RbLL4v41oqgmqJzaIVJYWxXw==">
```

And on the form as well:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="eTJnjnTDNbahT+W8ajr9fH8tGSC0wfismuNbwr0qtQkYoCoFqDm5kZ+nlwAnz+RbLL4v41oqgmqJzaIVJYWxXw==">
```

When trying through omniauth:

```
Started GET "/auth/linkedin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-09 23:10:47 -0100
I, [2017-07-09T23:10:47.726334 #33989]  INFO -- omniauth: (linkedin) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/auth/linkedin/callback?code=AQTYEqh7Ly5soZIFs_XfERBDL-EzRb-q_tkJgIIpLZWhlpcNLG6Ib9dQg2_74gRjDquZp_B3zTXjaBgpoRnJgbVoyVyMad0Ft8kjyMkTdhxPgWO5jbA&state=7f63139d28f961f32c789d07cc7ddfb6cd7c09b26af91733" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-09 23:10:48 -0100
I, [2017-07-09T23:10:48.980311 #33989]  INFO -- omniauth: (linkedin) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2017-07-09T23:10:48.980683 #33989] ERROR -- omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
E, [2017-07-09T23:10:48.981033 #33989] ERROR -- omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected

OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError (csrf_detected | CSRF detected):
```

What I already tried:

`protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: false` (& true)

Hardcoding in `config/secrets.yml`:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 0beec021fbe866716933a1da494be36f21bb6cf446ab7d315eb129706931bb2b284aa8e5507d0ab829abb8c2155958b47500aeadd5eace9cdc27643121cf6adf
```

&tried with:

```
secret_key_base: <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>
```

along with an Env variable

I previously used this on `config/environment.rb`:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'
# Load the app's custom environment variables here, before environments/*.rb
app_env_vars = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'initializers', 'app_env_vars.rb')
secret = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'initializers', 'secret_token.rb')
load(app_env_vars) if File.exists?(app_env_vars)
load(secret) if File.exists?(secret)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Tried without it, and passing all environment variables defined in that file to bash_profile terminal load.

So basically I ran out of ideas, if you have any, please share, thanks

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue after upgrading from 5.0.4 to 5.1.2. Were you able to find the root cause?

Comment: @Juampi I haven't - I did not look anymore since I solved it by copying the contents of the project into a fresh rails 5.1.2 project folder. Since it worked from the get-go doing that I would imagine it's some thing the `rails` updater is forgetting to change?

Comment: @Juampi perhaps it's even the devise installation? Maybe it would be worth copying your project folder, uninstall devise, remove the gem, bundle install, put the gem back, install, copy your custom devise controllers & views back in and see if it works? And if that works do the same on your "real" project

Comment: Considering this issue doesn't seem to be widespread, my guess is that it's something more subtle.

My issue is only present on staging and production, and I noticed that turning off CloudFlare seems to solve the problem.

But if your issue is present in development, then maybe they are not related after all...

Comment: @Juampi, actually now that I think of it, I copied it first to a fresh 5.0.4 Rails app, which worked just fine, and subsequently did the upgrade to 5.1.2 and didn't see any other problem? So the problem must be something else indeed in your case

Comment: I just noticed that changing the SSL settings on CloudFlare from "flexible" to "full" solves my issue. Not really sure why though... Anyway, thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Updating an old rails + devise app currently, and ran into a similar problem, when going from rails 4.2 to 5.0.

Turns out call sequence was the culprit:

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

worked in rails 4.2, whereas with 5.0 you need to call `protect_from_forgery` first:

```
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your before action prior to your protect_from_forgery and setting the prepend to false?  So your application controller would look something like this:

```
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: false

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, 
   :last_name])
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: 
   [:first_name, 
   :last_name])
 end

 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   user_path(id: resource.id)
 end
```

Alternatively what you can try to do is authenticate the user in your before_action since you're using oauth as shown in the code below, taken from this blog on switching from rails 4 to rails 5, feel free to read it.
(http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/06/rails-5-default-protect-from-forgery-prepend-false.html)

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 before_action :authenticate
 protect_from_forgery unless: -> { @authenticated_by.oauth? }

 private
 def authenticate
   if oauth_request?
     # authenticate with oauth
     @authenticated_by = 'oauth'.inquiry
   else
     # authenticate with cookies
     @authenticated_by = 'cookie'.inquiry
   end
 end
end
```

Hopefully one of these answers help you out.

Comment: thank you for taking the time and your suggestion. I tried the order and it didn't change anything. The problem with the @authenticated exception is that at that point I don't have a user authenticated - the CSRF invalidation happens on the callback from omniauth's oauth flow.

Comment: Sorry neither answer worked out.  I'm glad you are up and running by copying your rails 4 app to a brand new rails 5 app.  I'd definitely say writing the tests will be a worthwhile investment for the future. Lolz.  I still would like to know what the issue was and will do further digging and ask a few senior rails developers I know, I'll let you know if come up with anything.

Comment: no problem, thanks for looking at it. Probably between the rails:update and bundle update something got broke. Btw, I have it running right now with Rails 5.0.4, it worked fine since the beginning, just figuring out in which way I should move the /lib folder, but that's documented and boils down to choice. (before I tried directly updating to 5.1.2 - I'll try an update to 5.1.2 in the next few days and if that doesn't work I'll post somewhere as an issue?)

Comment: indeed I just updated to 5.1.2 and the only issue was having migrations without rails version in [v.n].

Comment: Yeah, looks like the leap from 4 to 5 is definitely  the culprit.  I'll continue to dig.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to pinpoint the problem. Effectively I just created a fresh rails 5 application with everything the same, copied everything over and it worked from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd suggest to update the app incrementally, i.e. to the latest patch version, which is 4.2.9 for the time being. Make sure it's still working and the test suite is green :) Then you'll be able to update the app to 5.0.4. Every time you upgrade the major or minor version remember to run the `rake rails:update` (`rails app:update` as of Rails 5.0+) to update configs and some other initially generated files. Here's a link to the [Rails guide on upgrading from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-2-to-rails-5-0).

Comment: thanks @dskecse I think I did a big jump by going directly to Rails 5.1, then I have no test suite, and certainly now I'm gonna start writing one lol. But starting a new rails app and basically copying over everything selectively, worked fine. Thanks either way, I'm gonna invest in writing some tests :x